# HLS is not playing on samsung TV but play on emulator

Tags: http-live-streaming, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to play Apple HLS stream on samsung TV:
https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8

Model code:UE40F5500
Version : 5.2481

Any idea why?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question, which would make it off-topic for SO.  Maybe try on [SU] with more details.

Comment: It might be changes in spec or something around it + there are many smart tv video developers here...

Comment: try to download the m3u8 and the if possible the content and see if TV supports HLS or the content (h264 profile) or not. I have seen the case where the content was h264 main profile and thus TV was not able to play.

Answer (score 1):

Playlist contains audio-only track. Usually SmartTV's not support this and refuse to play such playlist or throw error during track switching.

If you look at playlist:

```
$curl https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8
```

You will see last track without video:

```
#EXTM3U


#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=232370,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.4d4015"
gear1/prog_index.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=649879,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.4d401e"
gear2/prog_index.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=991714,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.4d401e"
gear3/prog_index.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1927833,CODECS="mp4a.40.2, avc1.4d401f"
gear4/prog_index.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=41457,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
gear0/prog_index.m3u8
```

Such track is required by Apple to allow playback of audio over mobile internet, so you can't use playlists from iOS on SmartTV.